# How do I list all processes owned by my user?

Tags: process

List all process names for my user.

I could do it with

```
ps aux | grep username
```

But the output would be like:

```
maythux  18343  0.0  0.1 1070868 34504 ?       Sl   Jun03   0:07 empathy
maythux  21562  0.0  0.1 703716 32104 ?        Sl   Jun10   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/blueman-applet
maythux  21574  0.0  0.0  53532  2408 ?        S    Jun10   0:00 /usr/bin/obex-data-server --no-daemon 
maythux  25197  0.0  1.0 2199840 258576 ?      Sl   May27   0:24 remmina
```

But I just want the output look like:

```
empathy
blueman-applet
obex-data-serve
remmina
```

So what is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Why won't you mark your answer as accepted?

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski Waiting for better answers if found

Answer (score 7):

You can easily do it with the `ps` command itself without any other tool:

```
ps -U user-name -o comm=
```

If you want to sort and remove duplicate entries you can do this:

```
ps -U user-name -o comm= | sort | uniq
```

Here's a sample of my output:

```
liferea
mission-control
nacl_helper
nautilus
nm-applet
notify-osd
nxclient.bin
nxnode.bin
obex-data-serve
okular
polkit-gnome-au
```

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completion, you can also use `pgrep`:

```
pgrep -lU foobar
```

this will match Real user ID of the user `foobar`. This will show the output with PIDs.

If you want only the process names, also with removing duplicates:

```
pgrep -lU foobar | cut -d' ' -f2 | sort -u  ##Using RUID

pgrep -lu foobar | cut -d' ' -f2 | sort -u  ##Using EUID
```